# C# Snowflake.Data Nuget connection failed in linux, succeeded in windows

Tags: c#, .net, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, .net-6.0

Code:

```
using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
{
conn.ConnectionString = "password=xxx;account=xxx;user=xxx;db=xxx;warehouse=xxx;role=xxx;host=xxx;region=xxx";

conn.Open();
}
```

When I run following same code and connectionString in windows, it connection opened. While run in linux, it throws:

Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.GetExceptions(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.get_Result()
at Snowflake.Data.Core.RestRequester.Post[T](IRestRequest request)
at Snowflake.Data.Core.Authenticator.BaseAuthenticator.Login()
at Snowflake.Data.Core.Authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.Snowflake.Data.Core.Authenticator.IAuthenticator.Authenticate()
at Snowflake.Data.Core.SFSession.Open()
at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open() -- .NET driver 2.0.0

Error Message: Error: Snowflake Internal Error: Unable to connect. One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.) SqlState: 08006, VendorCode: 270001, QueryId: -- .NET driver 2.1.1

Net6.0 framework

Any ideas about connection fail?

C# Snowflake.Data Nuget connection succeed in linux

Comment: Is it on the same machine?  Are you using Docker to run it under Linux on a Windows PC?

Comment: I used wsl to simulate linux env and dotnet run in wsl. They're are the same machine(windows pc).

Comment: From your WSL environment, can you ping the server?  Do you need to add some outbound/inbound ports?